# How Event Processing Work in KinecticJs

Tags: kineticjs

Canvas Container takes input (e.g. mouse[over,up,down] etc), how Kinetic JS identify that it has clicked for particular Node in the scene and how it maintains the stack information means which element will take event if multiple elements intersects

Answer (score 0):

You can detect which node has been clicked on by doing the following:

```
layer.on('click', function(e) {
  var node = e.targetNode;
  alert(node.getName());
});
```

And to answer your other question, the element that is on top will detect the mouse events, when multiple elements intersect.

You can use the `moveToTop()` function to move elements to the top to be able to detect the elements http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Node.html#moveToTop

```
circle.on('dragmove', function() {
  this.moveToTop();
});
```

See JSFiddle below for an example.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/MRZkc/)

Also, check the `getIntersection()` method http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#getIntersection to see which elements intersect a point.

Comment: If Stage has 'n' number of layers say n>100, and each layer has 'm' number of Shapes , say m > 20, then, on mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, ..... will it search linearly iterating to all layers and it's shapes, to determine, which shape's event to fire?